# Is salting a password pointless if someone gains access to the salt key? Off server salting?

Tags: hash, passwords, salt

Hearing about all the recent hacks at big tech firms, it made me wonder their use of password storage.

I know salting + hashing is accepted as being generally secure but ever example I've seen of salting has the salt key hard-coded into the password script which is generally stored on the same server.

So is it a logical solution to hash the user's password initially, pass that hash to a "salting server" or some function stored off-site, then pass back the salted hash?

The way I I'm looking at it is, if an intruder gains access to the server or database containing the stored passwords, they won't immediately have access to the salt key.

Answer (score 4):

No -- salt remains effective even if known to the attacker.

The idea of salt is that it makes a dictionary attack on a large number of users more difficult. Without salt, the attacker hashes all the words in a dictionary, and sees which match with your users' hashed paswords. With salt, he has to hash each word in the dictionary many times over (once for each possible hash value) to be certain of having one that fits each user.

This multiplication by several thousand (or possibly several million, depending on how large a salt you use) increases the time to hash all the values, and the storage need to store the results -- the point that (you hope) it's impractical.

I should add, however, that in many (most?) cases, a very large salt doesn't really add a lot of security. The problem is that if you use, say, a 24 bit salt (~16 million possible values) but have only, say, a few hundred users, the attacker can collect the salt values you're actually using ahead of time, then do his dictionary attack for only those values instead of the full ~16 million potential values. In short, your 24-bit salt adds only a tiny bit of difficulty beyond what a ~8 bit salt would have provided.

OTOH, for a large server (Google, Facebook, etc.) the story is entirely different -- a large salt becomes quite beneficial.

Answer (score 3):

Salting is useful even if intruder knows the salt.

If passwords are NOT salted, it makes possible to use widely available precomputed [rainbow tables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_table) to quickly attack your passwords.

If your password table was salted, it makes it very difficult to precompute rainbow tables - it is impractical to create rainbow table for every possible salt.

If you use random salt that is different for every password entry, and put it in plaintext right next to it, it makes very difficult for intruder to attack your passwords, short of brute force attack.

Comment: Makes sense. Seems like more effort than worth (unless its a site of significant worth or importance) for an attacker. Thanks for the quick reply.

Answer (score 1):

Salting passwords protects passwords against attacks where the attacker has a list of hashed passwords. There are some common hashing algorithms that hackers have tables for that allow them to look up a hash and retrieve the password. For this to work, the hacker has to have broken into the password storage and stolen the hashes.

If the passwords are salted, then the attacker must re-generate their hash tables, using the hashing algorithm and the salt. Depending on the hashing algorithm, this can take some time. To speed things up, hackers also use lists of the most common passwords and dictionary words. The idea of the salt is to slow an attacker down.

The best approach to use a different salt for each password, make it long and random, and it's ok to store the salt next to each password. This really slows an attacker down, because they would have to run their hash table generation for each individual password, for every combination of common passwords and dictionary words. This would make it implausible for an attacker to deduce strong passwords.

I had read a good article on this, which I can't find now. But Googling 'password salt' gives some good results. Have a look at [this article](http://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm).

Comment: Thanks. Just what I wanted to know.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to point out, that the scheme you described with the hard-coded salt, is actually **not a salt**, instead it works like a key or a pepper. Salt and pepper solve different problems.

A **salt** should be generated randomly for every password, and can be stored together with the hashed password in the database. It can be stored plain text, and fullfills it's purpose even when known to the attacker.

A **pepper** is a secret key, that will be used for all passwords. It will not be stored in the database, instead it should be deposited in a safe place. If the pepper is known to the attacker, it becomes useless.

I tried to explain the differences in a small [tutorial](http://www.martinstoeckli.ch/hash/en/index.php), maybe you want to have a look there.

Answer (score 0):

> Makes sense. Seems like more effort than worth (unless its a site of significant worth or importance) for an attacker.

all sites small or large, important or not, should take password hashing as high importance

as long as each hash has its own large random salt then yes it does become mostly impracticable, if each hash uses an static salt you can use Rainbow tables to weed out the users hashs who used password1 for example

using an good hashing algorithm is also important as well (using MD5 or SHA1 is nearly like using plaintext with the mutli gpu setups these days) use scrypt if not then bcrypt or if you have to use PBKDF2 then (you need the rounds to be very high)